# I am trying to set-up Centrify for Apache under a Solaris 10 machine

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication

I lean on the documentation of the product Centrify which can be downloaded from the official site: http://www.centrify.com/downloads/public/documentation/current/centrify_dc_apache.pdf
This documentation is called: "Centrify DirectControl Authentication Guide for Apache".

My Unix machine is under Solaris 10. I have the following Centrify package already installed:

```
> pkginfo | grep -i centrify
system CentrifyDC Centrify DirectControl Agent
```

But, the documentation speaks about the following folder that I cannot found: /usr/share/centrifydc/apache. The folder /usr/share/centrifydc/ exists.

That is why, I think I miss a package (something as Centrify for Apache module) ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are absolutely right. You are missing the "DirectControl for Apache" package. The missing directories get created as a part of "DirectControl for Apache" package installation. Please contact us at support@centrify.com and we will be more than happy to help you out.

Thanks
Sumana